# Backbone Scope best practice for accessing variables

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Can someone explain scope to me in Backbone? Is the best way in the example below to use a get method to retrieve the value of a default variable?

If I don't use the get method, my array comes up as undefined.

```
App.Models.Site = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        testArray: [1, 2, 3]
    },

    initialize: function(){
        console.log('initialize', this.testArray); // logs undefined
        console.log('initialize', this.get('testArray')); // logs [1, 2, 3]

        this.test();
    },

    test: function(){
        console.log('initialize', this.testArray); // logs undefined
        console.log('test', this.get('testArray')); // logs [1, 2, 3]
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you want to get the default value for `testArray` or the actual value of `testArray` for the model instance? Does my post answer your question? I'm though I initially misunderstood what you were looking for and edited my answer, but now I think it might have been correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `defaults` value with `App.Models.Site.prototype.defaults`.

If you use `get` (see below) you will retrieve the current `testArray` value of your model instance. This will not always be the same across instances.

---

The model properties are stored inside an `.attributes` property of the model instead of the model itself. The only way to retrieve the value of a model property is to use `get(propertyName)`.

The reason it's done this way is because `set` doesn't just change the value of the object but also triggers events to update the UI with the new value etc. If you could do `this.testArray` instead of `this.get('testArray')` it would be reasonable that you can also assign values to `this.testArray` - but that would break things.

For this reason you also shouldn't use `.attributes` to assign values - no event handlers would be triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Several things.

First, in `defaults`, you're defining model fields, not (object) fields of your model instance.  The model fields are what gets serialized to your data store.  Your object fields are just part of your object serving whatever purpose you need them to.

Secondly, I think your defaults might be better written using a method to construct the default values:

```
....
defaults: function(){
         return {
        testArray: [1, 2, 3]
         };
      }, 
...
```

So that each model starts with a copy of `[1, 2, 3]` instead of each model sharing a reference to one and only array that is `[1, 2, 3]` (if any of your models change that array, say if you do `this.get('testArray')[0]=4`, suddenly the default values will look very different).  That won't ever happen if you only `set` the field to a new array value, of course.